# How can I reverse the query

Tags: laravel

how can i reverse the following query.

Column Types:

```
name: string
up_city: integer
```

Query :

```
$data = Cities::get();
foreach ($data as $row){
   $c = Cities::find($row->up_city);
   return $c->name;
   // istanbul
}
```

I want to search "keywords"

```
$keyword = "istanbul";
$data = Cities:: ???
```

fixed: apokryfos thank you

Comment: Define the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction) between city and up_city and then you could do `Cities::whereHas('upCity', fn ($q) => $q->where('name', $keyword))` (assuming you named the relationship `upCity`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```php
Cities::where('name', 'istanbul');
```

Comment: up_city(integer id) == 'istanbul'